# Linq expression to join a list and a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, denormalization

I have a list of part numbers:

```
var parts = new List<string> {"part1", "part2", "part3"};
```

I also have a dictionary of quantities for these part numbers:

```
var quantities = new Dictionary<string, int> {{"part1", 45}, {"part3", 25}};
```

Given a delimiter of `|`, I need to arrange these values in a flat file like so:

```
SalesRep|part1|part2|part3
Mr. Foo|45||25
```

What I'd like to do is define a string that no matter what values are in `parts` and `quantities`, I can tack this on to the sales rep name to resemble the example above.

It seems like I should be able to do this with a `string.Join()` on an enumerable LINQ operation, but I can't figure out what statement will get me the `IEnumerable<string>` result from joining `parts` and `quantities`.  It thought that would be a `.Join()`, but the signature doesn't seem right.  Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var parts = new List<string> { "part1", "part2", "part3" };
 var quantities = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "part1", 45 }, { "part3", 25 } };

        var result = string.Join("|", 
               from p in parts select quantities.ContainsKey(p) 
                        ? quantities[p].ToString() : "");
```

Comment: Yeah I was overcomplicating it.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it exactly produced the result I was looking for, but @BrokenGlass let me know that I was way overthinking it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this perhaps?

```
var partValues = parts.Select(x => quantities.ContainsKey(x) ? quantities[x] : 0);
```

Basically for each item in the parts list you either pick the value from your dictionary, or if it doesn't exist 0.

To make this a little more interesting you could define a generic extension method on `IDictionary<T,U>` that makes this a little more readable:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static U GetValueOrDefault<T,U>(this IDictionary<T, U> dict, T key)
    {
        if(dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return dict[key];
        }
        return default(U);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply write:

```
var partValues = parts.Select(quantities.GetValueOrDefault);
```